# Error: no operator "==" matches these operands

Tags: c++

This isn't actually my code, but I need help right here. Since I'm new to coding, I don't know how to fix this problem.

```
bool GetProcessEntryByName(string name, PROCESSENTRY32* pe) {
    auto snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cerr << "Tool helper cannot be created" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (!Process32First(snapshot, pe)) {
        cerr << "Tool helper cannot retrieve the first entry of process list" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    do {
        if (pe->szExeFile == name) {
            snapshot ? CloseHandle(snapshot) : 0;
            return true;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(snapshot, pe));

    snapshot ? CloseHandle(snapshot) : 0;
    return false;
}
```

And the error occurs at: `if (pe->szExeFile == name)....`

Output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: EzExecV2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(45,28): error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\guiddef.h(192,15): message : could be 'bool operator ==(const GUID &,const GUID &)'
1>D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\random(2056,24): message : or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::bernoulli_distribution &,const std::bernoulli_distribution &)'
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(45,28): message : or       'built-in C++ operator==(WCHAR [260], WCHAR [260])'
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(45,28): message : while trying to match the argument list '(std::string, WCHAR [260])'
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(106,24): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from '__int64' to 'DWORD'
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(106,9): warning C4309: 'argument': truncation of constant value
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(111,27): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from '__int64' to 'DWORD'
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(111,9): warning C4309: 'argument': truncation of constant value
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(133,23): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from '__int64' to 'DWORD'
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(133,9): warning C4309: 'argument': truncation of constant value
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(137,24): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from '__int64' to 'DWORD'
1>E:\Desktop\Coding\Test\main.cpp(137,9): warning C4309: 'argument': truncation of constant value
1>Done building project "Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm using Unicode Char Set

I don't know if there is a more detailed log for the build. If there is, tell me where I can find it.

Comment: The error message will state exactly what types are being compared and this usually greatly speeds solving the problem. You should add this information, the complete error message from the full build output, to the question.

Comment: Looks like `pe->szExeFile` isn't of type `std::string`. You'll need to consult the docs of [`PROCESSENTRY32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-processentry32).

Comment: Sometimes you can get miracles by flipping the comparison around. `std::string`'s `==` overloads have a direct path to comparison with a `char` array, but I'm not sure of the reverse. You know, I'm going to knock out some really stupid test code to see what happens these days.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this code is being compiled with `UNICODE` enabled, so `pe->szExeFile` will be a `wchar_t[]`, which cannot be compared to a `std::string` using `operator==`.

Comment: Bang! Remy for the win: https://godbolt.org/z/MG64hv

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, `pe->szExeFile` is not a `std::string`, it is a `TCHAR[]` array.   @user4581301 `std::string` has an overloaded [`operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) that supports a `char*` string on the left-hand side.

Comment: That's what I thought, too and trying it out confirmed it. I'd written the question off as non-reproducible until your unicode comment. Funny thing is [the doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-processentry32) calls it a `CHAR`: `CHAR      szExeFile[MAX_PATH];`. Got to be an alias somewhere I'm missing.

Comment: @Remy Yes, I said it's something different (which is unknown in the c++ standard context).

Comment: @user4581301 you are looking at the doc for the ANSI version of `PROCESSENTRY32`.  When `UNICODE` is defined, `PROCESSENTRY32` is an alias for [`PROCESSENTRY32W`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-processentry32w) instead.

Comment: The fiends! There it is right below `PROCESSENTRY32` on the side bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are compiling the project with Unicode, so [`Process32FirstW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32firstw) will be called instead of `Process32First()`. Change your function to take `wstring` as parameter or convert `name` to `wstring` before comparison:

```
std::wstring wName(name.begin(), name.end());
if (pe->szExeFile == wName) {
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "wcscmp()" to compare your "wchar*" variables

```
if (!wcscmp(pe->szExeFile, wName))
{}
```

Comment: compiling in Release mode instead of Debug mode also fixed my problem